# Ghostscript Dll with Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am using Ghostscript Dll with threads, but its throwing an exception of AccessVoilation, Can any one help why is it so, any help would greately be appericiated Regards: Usman

Comment: Infact in my scenario, i want to convert pdf file to image, for that purpose i am using ghostscript dll, but its not working with threads..

Comment: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/08/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-aspnet.html

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=2c5f5b0560e374cb&id=2C5F5B0560E374CB%21423

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation states that:

> The Win32 DLL gsdll32.dll can be used by multiple programs simultaneously, but only once within each process.

Therefore you will need to use child processes, not threads, to run Ghostscript instances concurrently.